# Does adding an explicit column of SHA-256 hash for a CLOB field improve the search(exact match) performance on that CLOB field

Tags: oracle, indexing, sha256, clob

We have a requirement to implement a table(probably an orable db table or a mssql db table) as follows:

1. One column stores a string value, the length of this string value is highly variable, typically from several bytes to 500 megabytes(occasionally beyond 1 gigabytes )
2. Based on above, we decided to use CLOB type in db.(using system file is not an option somehow)
3. The table is very large up to several millions of records.
4. One of most frequent and important operation against this table is searching records by this CLOB column and the search string needs to EXACTlY match this CLOB column value.

My question is besides adding an index on CLOB column, whether we need to do some particular optimisation to improve the search performance?

One of my team member suggested adding an extra column in which to calculate SHA-256 hash of CLOB column above and search by this hash value instead of CLOB column. In terms of his opinion, the grounds of doing so are hash values are equal length other than variable so that indexing on that makes search faster.

However, I don't think this way makes big difference because assuming adding an explicit hash improves search performance database should be intelligent enough to do it by its own, likely storing this hash value in some hidden places of db system. Why bother we developers do it explicitly, on the other hand, this hash value theoretically creates collision although it's rare.

The only benefit I can imagine is when the client side of database does a search of which the keyword is very large, you can reduce network roundtrip by hashing this large value to a small length value, therefore network transferring is faster.

So any database gurus, please shed lights on this question. Many thanks!

Comment: I would expect indexing to be faster on variable-length values. Why do you think equal length is better?

Comment: Hi shmosel, thanks for replying. I don't know which one is faster, but my teammate thinks of the benefits of doing hash are making values all same length and much shorter than original CLOB values so that the index will be faster. I also suspected it's not true.

Comment: Depending on how strings are implemented, the length could be the first line of defense when rejecting a potential match. Having fixed-length strings forces the indexer to start comparing them letter by letter.

Comment: The network overhead may still be an important consideration though, especially if you have objects as large as 500mb.

Comment: Good points! Shmosel, thanks again. But that being said, the inability of indexing a CLOB field probably makes hashing more sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular indexes don't work on CLOB columns.  Instead you would need to create an Oracle Text index, which is primarily for full text searching of key words/phrases, rather than full text matching.

In contrast by computing a hash function on the column data, you can then create an index on the hash value since it's short enough to fit in a standard VARCHAR2 or RAW column.  Such a hash function can significantly reduce your search space when trying to find exact matches.

Further your concern over hash collisions, while not unfounded can be mitigated.  First off, hash collisions are relatively rare, but when they do occur, the documents are unlikely to be very similar, so a direct text comparison could be used in situations where a collision is detected.  **A**lternatively due to the way hashing functions work, where small changes to the original document result in significant changes in the hash value, and where the same change to different documents affects the hash value differently, you could compute a secondary hash of a subset (or super set) of the original text to act as a collision avoidance mechanism.

Comment: Hi Sentinel, thank you so much for the answer. That's very helpful.

Comment: I'm wondering what if I don't use CLOB, instead, I use a VARCHAR2 on which I setup a large length limit. Does this way make hashing against this VARCHAR2 useless since I can easily add an index on  VARCHAR2 regardless how this field's length is variable?

Comment: As of Oracle 11g VARCHAR2 has a limit of 4000 bytes in tables and SQL and 32768 bytes in PL/SQL, I believe the limits in Tables and SQL have been increased in 12c, but I'm not sure of the new limits, though still <= 32768.  Whereas CLOBs can easily handle multiple GB worth of data.

Comment: Thanks Sentinel, that's very helpful.